# Display all data from an API in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display all data I want from Matomo API but I can only display them one by one

I don't know if I should do a for loop and where or how.

My code :

```
<?php
include 'TabMetrique.php';

$token_auth = '*********';

getMetrique($metrique);

$url = "http://localhost/matomo/";
$url .= "?module=API&method=".getMetrique($metrique)."&idSite=1";
$url .= "&period=month&date=2022-05-14";
$url .= "&format=JSON";
$url .= "&token_auth=$token_auth";

    $fetched = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = json_decode($fetched,true);



// case error
if (!$content) {
    print("No data found");
} 
else {
    print("<h1>Métrique Matomo</h1>\n");
   
    foreach ($content as $row) {
            if ($content == $row){
                $contentMetrique = htmlspecialchars($row["label"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // à changer pour afficher toute les métrique
                $hits = $row['nb_visits'];
               print("<b>$contentMetrique</b> ($hits visits)<br>\n");
            }else{
                print("$row<b> action or visit</b>");
            }
            
    } 
}
?>
```

My IF condition doesn't work but that's not a problem at the moment

And TabMetrique.php :

```
<?php
$metrique [0] = 'DevicesDetection.getModel'; // appareil utilisé
$metrique [1] =  'UserCountry.getCountry'; // Pays
$metrique [2] =  'UserCountry.getContinent'; //continent
$metrique [3] =   'UserCountry.getRegion'; // Region
$metrique [4] =   'UserCountry.getCity'; // Ville
$metrique [5] =   'UserId.getUsers'; // recupérer les UsersID
$metrique [6] =   'UserLanguage.getLanguage'; // Langue
$metrique [7] =    'VisitFrequency.get'; // Visiteur récurrent
$metrique [8] =    'VisitsSummary.get'; 
$metrique [9] =   'VisitsSummary.getVisits'; //visiteur
$metrique [10] =   'VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors'; // visiteur unique

function getMetrique($metrique){
    return $metrique[9];
}
?>
```

someone can help me ? thx

Comment: Is that last code fragment called `TabMetrique.php`

Comment: Yes, I call the function ```getMetrique``` in my main code

Comment: I woudl say you need to look at the documention for the Matomo API to see if there is another entry point for multiple access

Comment: No matomo dont have a multiple access. I can do display all data in php by calling each method one after the other but I don't know how to do that

Comment: when i do a foreach in my array. this code ``` $url .= "?module=API&method=".$value."&idSite=1"; ``` take only the last one element in my array. but I want the code the first element and do the code, ect

Answer (score 0):

Well first remove the function it is unnecessary, all you need is an array and then process it with a forech loop.

code TabMetrique.php

```
<?php
$metrique[0]  = 'DevicesDetection.getModel'; // appareil utilisé
$metrique[1]  = 'UserCountry.getCountry'; // Pays
$metrique[2]  = 'UserCountry.getContinent'; //continent
$metrique[3]  = 'UserCountry.getRegion'; // Region
$metrique[4]  = 'UserCountry.getCity'; // Ville
$metrique[5]  = 'UserId.getUsers'; // recupérer les UsersID
$metrique[6]  = 'UserLanguage.getLanguage'; // Langue
$metrique[7]  = 'VisitFrequency.get'; // Visiteur récurrent
$metrique[8]  = 'VisitsSummary.get'; 
$metrique[9]  = 'VisitsSummary.getVisits'; //visiteur
$metrique[10] = 'VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors'; // visiteur unique

?>
```

Now a simple foreach loop to control getting the names from the metrique array

```
<?php
include 'TabMetrique.php';

$token_auth = '*********';

$url = "http://localhost/matomo/?";
$url .= "period=month&date=2022-05-14";
$url .= "&format=JSON&module=API";
$url .= "&token_auth=$token_auth&idSite=1";

foreach ($metrique as $metric) {
    //get static part of the url and add dynamic bit to it
    // note i moved the dynamic part to be last, that should not matter to the api

    $u = $url . "&method=$metric";

    $content = json_decode(file_get_contents($u), true);

    // case error
    if (!$content) {
        print("No data found");
    } else {
        print("<h1>Métrique Matomo</h1>\n");
   
        foreach ($content as $row) {
            if ($content == $row){
                $contentMetrique = htmlspecialchars($row["label"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // à changer pour afficher toute les métrique
                $hits = $row['nb_visits'];
                print("<b>$contentMetrique</b> ($hits visits)<br>\n");
            }else{
                print("$row<b> action or visit</b>");
            }
            
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean `&method` its the same thing as when it was in your original code